# Execute Multiple features using testNG.xml

Tags: cucumber-jvm

I am executing multiple feature files with different set of parameters, each feature file is one testcase in testNg.xml file it does the execution for all features which I am sending from testng.xml bt it creates the report only for last feature file execution, I am using net.masterthught reports. 
here is sample testNg.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="2" name="TestSuite" parallel="tests">
  <test name="Test1">
    <parameter name="EnvironmentName" value="DEV"/>
    <parameter name="param1" value="value1"/>
    <parameter name="param2" value="value2"/>
    <parameter name="FeatureName" value="featurename.feature"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="RunnerClass"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 
<test name="Test2">
    <parameter name="EnvironmentName" value="DEV"/>
    <parameter name="param1" value="value1"/>
    <parameter name="param2" value="value2"/>
    <parameter name="FeatureName" value="featurename.feature"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="RunnerClass"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/bdd-syntax.html) which support Gherkin, where driver management, resource management and execution configuration are taken care by the framework. It is dedicated framework built upon TestNG  for web, mobile web, mobile native, and webservices functional test automation. For example above config file can look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite thread-count="2" name="TestSuite" parallel="tests">
  <test name="Test1">
    <parameter name="EnvironmentName" value="DEV"/>
    <parameter name="param1" value="value1"/>
    <parameter name="param2" value="value2"/>
    <parameter name="scenario.file.loc" value="featurename.feature"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.gherkin.GherkinScenarioFactory"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 
<test name="Test2">
    <parameter name="EnvironmentName" value="DEV"/>
    <parameter name="param1" value="value1"/>
    <parameter name="param2" value="value2"/>
    <parameter name="scenario.file.loc" value="featurename.feature"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="com.qmetry.qaf.automation.step.client.gherkin.GherkinScenarioFactory"/>
    </classes>
  </test> 
</suite>
```

Different combinations you can achieve through [execution configuration](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/creating_configuration_file.html).

Refer [Gherkin with QAF](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html)